# Display the rate of change for all tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, statistics

I noticed that PHP has recently over taken asp.net.  It also looks like PHP is growing faster than even just ".net" or java tags.  It would be cool if SO would show the rate of change or rather the 1st derivative of tags.  It would also be cool to sort all tags by the rate at which they are growing.

I think that this will produce more accurate statistics than [TIOBE](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html).

Comment: Yay! Tag calculus!

Comment: @mmyers: Int(ASP.NET, 0..42) = ?

Comment: My heart hopes that tags like `subjective` and `career-development` are waning, but my brain knows better.

Comment: @gnovice: Your brain deceives you. http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/tags/?subjective+career-development

Comment: @Greg: Looks promising, but since it's a relative percentage it could indicate 2 things. Either the `subjective` questions are being asked less, or other questions are being asked more.

Comment: @gnovice: or, subjective questions aren't actually being tagged as such. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I direct you to the [Stack Overflow Tag Trends](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/tagtrend.html) page, which shows the proportion of questions per tag relative to the total number of questions, graphed over time. The data available today is the latest (March dump, which includes up to the end of February 2010). The final week sometimes shows some glitches due to it usually being a partial week.

PHP is indeed growing quickly.

Comment: cool! I wish this was expanded.

Comment: @user142380: expanded to what? If you're interested in specific comparisons, I can certainly add them.

Comment: You are comparing a good set of tags,  I can't think of better ones off hand.  It would be nice if this was an integrated feature that would allow you to compare arbitrary tags.  Perhaps you could add multiple tags to better extrapolate different information like is PHP usage growing faster on Windows, Linux, Solaris or BSD?

Comment: @user142380: see the latest version, you can now choose your own tags to compare: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41450/interactive-tag-trend-comparison-page