# Interactive tag trend comparison page

Tags: discussion, tags, data-dump, graphs, trends

My Sunday afternoon project this weekend was to add a bit of jQuery pixie dust to the tag trend graph page. The new [Stack Overflow Tag Trends](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/tags/) page allows you to choose which tags to compare and produces a graph interactively. You can also capture a link to a particular graph, for example the history for the [homework](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/tags/?homework) tag is amusing.

Available tags are those that have been used for 100 or more questions (1835 tags total at the moment).

Here's a recent [newsworthy graph](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41344/display-the-rate-of-change-for-all-tags):

[image]

Comment: Wow, pretty awesome.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: why is Forth excluded? Today I tried with these four tags: jquery python django forth. Forth is not a very active tag, but still.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill Can you update the data? It look a little outdated.

Comment: @Horcrux7: I fixed the post, it was pointing to old links. The top level stats page (for all SE sites) is: http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/

Comment: I think it's informative to [see how few Facebook questions there are in comparison to Android questions](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/tags/?c%23+java+android+facebook), especially with all the recent discussion about Facebook.SO. And @Greg, yer links are broken!  :)

Comment: @Chris: *Your* link is broken, I had already fixed the one in the post :)

Comment: Well, yes. . .but I copied the link directly from the **[link]** button on [your site](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/tags/). Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @Chris: My apologies, you are quite right. The `[link]` button should be fixed now.

Comment: Could you re-run your scripts to update the graphs with the data since 2012?

Comment: Some tags are missing, is there anything we can do about that?

Answer (score 7):

Nice piece of work, @Greg Hewgill.

It will be interesting to see how the the numbers develop as Stack Overflow trends towards a more industry-wide audience.

See, the problem with these "growth rates" is that they reflect primarily the growth of Stack Overflow, not the industry in general. Stack Overflow **started with a disproportionately strong .NET presence** because of [Joel](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/04/16.html)'s and [Jeff](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/introducing-stackoverflow-com.html)'s influence in drawing the initial audience.

So when you see a *percentage* gain in technologies like PHP or a *percentage* loss in .NET, that doesn't (necessarily) reflect anything more than the normalization of Stack Overflow's audience coming more in line with the true developer population.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely cool.  And intriguing.  Yay for the low number of bugs on Meta  :O)

[image]